# Laravel Many to Many relationship for 3 tables

Tags: laravel, relation

i've 3 tables Branches,Subjects,Teachers

Branches and subjects already many to many.

i've CRUD for teacher,when i create teacher i insert info to user model to add new user with type teacher.

i want to make relation to allow me combine teachers/branches/subjects.

for example when i'm creating teacher i need to select branch/branches and subject/subjects that this teacher related to.

any hint allows me to do this ?

Comment: read the docs on many to many relations, and give it a try

Comment: many to many support 2 models not 3

Comment: Yes, You can .
You have to define another `pivot_Table` which hold id's of (`teacher`, `branches`, `subject` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i it convert for you

If I get it right, you have established the many-to-many-relationships between every two of the three models

(Teacher, Branche & Subject).

Instead, you should establish the many-to many between any two models

of your choice and treat the third model as a pivot. For example:

Teacher.php

class Teacher extends Model

{

public function branches()

{

return $this->belongsToMany(Branche::class)->withPivot('subject');

}

}

Branche.php

class Branche extends Model

{

public function teachers()

{

return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class)->withPivot('subject');

}
}

view.blade.php

@foreach($teachers as $teacher)

@foreach($teacher->branches as $branc)

{{ $branc->name }}  {{ $branc->pivot->subject }}

@endforeach

@endforeach

Comment: That what i exactly did and it works,Thank you for your effort.